# href is not generated when ui-sref is used after migration form AngularJS from 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have migrated for AngularJS 1.6.10 to 1.7.5. After migration almost, all links are broken. A href is not generated.

```
<a href="" ui-sref="app.state1.substate">Link</a>
```

Expected Result:

```
<a href="/app/state1/substate/" ui-sref="app.state1.substate">Link</a>
```

But after migration:

```
<a href ui-sref="app.state1.substate">Link</a>
```

Comment: Try and delete the empty href tag or use it as `href` without he empty value.

Comment: It is the bug in angularJs 1.7.5. I have made an issue. 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/16809